# How do I fetch individual columns from my tables using php and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new to PHP and MySQL and I'm trying to pull data from individual columns to input into my website. Now, I've seen tons of examples; however, I feel like I must be missing something simple because I can't seem to get it to work. How do I actually pull individual columns and do this repeatedly for everything in that particular table?

Here is my PHP function I'm trying to run:

```
getPosts();

function getPosts() {

    // Create connection
    $link = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    $sql = 'SELECT 
                        title,
                        date,
                        body,
                        author,
                        owner
                    FROM
                        posts';

    $results = $link->query($sql);

    echo "<div class='post'>
        <div class='post-title'>
            <span class='post-heading'>" . $row["title"] .
                "</span><span class='post-date'>" . $row["date"] .
                "</span>
        </div>

        <div class='post-body'>
            <p>" . $row["body"] . "</p>
        </div>

        <div class='post-footer'>
            <hr/>
            <span class='author-note'><span class='glyphicon
                glyphicon-triangle-top'></span> <i>Posted by
               <a href='#'>" . $row["author"] . "</a> | Owned
               by <a href='#'>" . $row["owner"] . "</a></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>";

    $link->close();
}
```

And then I'm getting these errors when I run this:

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (28000/1045):
  Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
  in /home/mynameis/public_html/bardassets/main.php on line 13

Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in
  /home/mynameis/public_html/bardassets/main.php on line 24

Warning: mysqli::close(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in
  /home/mynameis/public_html/bardassets/main.php on line 41
```

I guess I just want to know what key part I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it like this as you have not defined $row. Also you have not defined $servername, $username, $password, $dbname variables which usedto create mysqli connection. Please add it. it will work

```
function getPosts() {

$servername = 'host';
$username = 'username';
$password = 'passwprd';
$dbname = 'dbname';
// Create connection
$link = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql = 'SELECT 
                    title,
                    date,
                    body,
                    author,
                    owner
                FROM
                    posts';

$results = $link->query($sql);
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<div class='post'>
        <div class='post-title'>
            <span class='post-heading'>" . $row["title"] .
                "</span><span class='post-date'>" . $row["date"] .
                "</span>
        </div>

        <div class='post-body'>
            <p>" . $row["body"] . "</p>
        </div>

        <div class='post-footer'>
            <hr/>
            <span class='author-note'><span class='glyphicon
                glyphicon-triangle-top'></span> <i>Posted by
               <a href='#'>" . $row["author"] . "</a> | Owned
               by <a href='#'>" . $row["owner"] . "</a></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>";
}

$link->close();
  }
```

Comment: I'm getting two more errors as a result: Warning: mysqli::query()::: 

Couldn't fetch mysqli in /home/mynameis/public_html/bardassets/main.php on line 24 &&&&


Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in /home/mynameis/public_html/bardassets/main.php on line 26

Comment: please add you servername, username, password ,dbname in the variables I have defined. the error is caused becaused mysqli connection has not defined due to empty undefined variables inside new mysqli() instanciation

Comment: Ah, I had my variables declared outside of the function and that was screwing it up. What's the php equivalent to static variables?

Comment: create connection outside function and use that $link as global inside your function

Answer (score 0):

It simply says one or more of your `$servername`, `$username`, `$password`, `$dbname` is/are wrong.

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (28000/1045):
  Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
  in /home/mynameis/public_html/bardassets/main.php on line 13
```

Comment: How can that be? I've checked the connection prior and it said it connected successfully. I'm very confused as to how that error is occurring.